# Printing and editing multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, printing

Im trying to create a small text based game, and to achieve this I am created 20 lists, added 75 spaces to fill the lists, then printed each of the lists one at a time, all at the same time. I was hoping to then be able to edit the lists at certain positions so that when the lists were printed again, the console would display text where I placed it. This is what I came up with so far...

The desired effect was to have the console print this:

```
  ============================ 
  =                          = 
  =      TEXT ADVENTURE:     = 
  =    WAR OF ZE MONSTERS    = 
  =                          =
  ============================
```

But instead I get this:

```
===========================
```

I don't know exactly what is happening with my draw function or my write function but (to me) it would seem as if it should work.

Any help would be amazing as I am relatively new to python. Thanks in advance!

```
import time

#
#  Joel Williams
#
#  Purpose: Create a Working Text Engine
#

# start of classes



class line():
    def __init__(self):
        counter = 0
        self.list = []
        while (counter != lineSize):
            self.list.append(' ')
            counter = counter + 1

class cursor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cursorPosY = 0
        self.cursorPosX = 0
        self.cursorPos = [self.cursorPosY, self.cursorPosX]

    def setCursorPos(self,y,x):
        self.cursorPosY = y
        self.cursorPosX = x
        self.cursorPos = [self.cursorPosY, self.cursorPosX]



# end of cursor class
# start of peliminary declarations



lineSize = 74
term = cursor()

_1  = line()
_2  = line()
_3  = line()
_4  = line()
_5  = line()
_6  = line()
_7  = line()
_8  = line()
_9  = line()
_10 = line()
_11 = line()
_12 = line()
_13 = line()
_14 = line()
_15 = line()
_16 = line()
_17 = line()
_18 = line()
_19 = line()
_20 = line()



# end of preliminary declarations
# start of preliminary functions

def delLine(x):
    del x[:]
    counter = 0
    x = []
    while (counter != lineSize):
        x.append(' ')
        counter = counter + 1

def clear():
    # clears all lists
    delLine(_1.list)
    delLine(_2.list)
    delLine(_3.list)
    delLine(_4.list)
    delLine(_5.list)
    delLine(_6.list)
    delLine(_7.list)
    delLine(_8.list)
    delLine(_9.list)
    delLine(_10.list)
    delLine(_11.list)
    delLine(_12.list)
    delLine(_13.list)
    delLine(_14.list)
    delLine(_15.list)
    delLine(_16.list)
    delLine(_17.list)
    delLine(_18.list)
    delLine(_19.list)
    delLine(_20.list)

def clearLine():
    if(term.cursorPosY == 0):    
        delLine(_1.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 1):    
        delLine(_2.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 2):    
        delLine(_3.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 3):    
        delLine(_4.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 4):    
        delLine(_5.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 5):    
        delLine(_6.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 6):    
        delLine(_7.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 7):    
        delLine(_8.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 8):    
        delLine(_9.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 9):    
        delLine(_10.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 10):    
        delLine(_11.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 11):    
        delLine(_12.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 12):    
        delLine(_13.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 13):    
        delLine(_14.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 14):    
        delLine(_15.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 15):    
        delLine(_16.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 16):    
        delLine(_17.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 17):    
        delLine(_18.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 18):    
        delLine(_19.list)

    elif(term.cursorPosY == 19):    
        delLine(_20.list)

def draw():
    # draws the lists
    # each lists is a line (Y)
    # each of the list's properties are the text (X)
    i1 = ''.join(_1.list)
    i2 = ''.join(_2.list)
    i3 = ''.join(_3.list)
    i4 = ''.join(_4.list)
    i5 = ''.join(_5.list)
    i6 = ''.join(_6.list)
    i7 = ''.join(_7.list)
    i8 = ''.join(_8.list)
    i9 = ''.join(_9.list)
    i10 = ''.join(_10.list)
    i11 = ''.join(_11.list)
    i12 = ''.join(_12.list)
    i13 = ''.join(_13.list)
    i14 = ''.join(_14.list)
    i15 = ''.join(_15.list)
    i16 = ''.join(_16.list)
    i17 = ''.join(_17.list)
    i18 = ''.join(_18.list)
    i19 = ''.join(_19.list)
    i20 = ''.join(_20.list)
    print i1
    print i2
    print i3
    print i4
    print i5
    print i6
    print i7
    print i8
    print i9
    print i10
    print i11
    print i12
    print i13
    print i14
    print i15
    print i16
    print i17
    print i18
    print i19
    print i20
    print i20

def write(str):
    # changes the lists
    c = 0
    for i in str:
        if term.cursorPosX > lineSize:
            term.cursorPosX = 0
            if term.cursorPosY > 19:
                term.cursorPosY = 0
            else:
                term.cursorPosY = term.cursorPosY + 1

        if term.cursorPosY is 0:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 1:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 2:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 3:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 4:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 5:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 6:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 7:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 8:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 9:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 10:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 11:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 12:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 13:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 14:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 15:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 16:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 17:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 18:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

        elif term.cursorPosY is 19:
            _1.list[term.cursorPosX] = str[c]
            c = c + 1
            term.cursorPosX = term.cursorPosX + 1

def writf(str,y,x):
    write(str)
    term.setCursorPos(y,x)

def ask(x):
    i = raw_input(x)
    return i

def wait(i):
    time.sleep(i)

def cursorPos(y,x):
    term.setCursorPos(y,x)



# end of preliminary functions
# start of actual stuff
# start of Main Stuff

# start of game functions




def startScreen():
    writf('============================ ',8,10)
    writf('=                          = ',9,10)
    writf('=      TEXT ADVENTURE:     = ',10,10)
    writf('=    WAR OF ZE MONSTERS    = ',11,10)
    writf('=                          = ',10,10)
    writf('============================ ',12,10)
    draw()
    wait(5)



# end of game functions



def Main():


    startScreen()


Main()



# end of Stuff

# end of actual stuff
```

Comment: Ouch, that's an absurd amount of code duplication. How do you manage changes when the same code needs to be changed in fifty-eleven different places?

Comment: Did you think of having a list of lines, rather than a separate variable for each line?

Comment: `term.cursorPosY is 19` will surprise you. While `1000 is 1000`, `(500 + 500) is not 1000`. Don't use `is` for numeric comparisons

Comment: @tripleee do you think you could help me out by showing me how to reduce the code duplication? I am relatively new to this stuff.

Comment: @Eric i did, but I couldn't get that to work at all

Comment: Ideally, one piece of logic should only exist once in your code base. That is why we have functions, loops, and conditionals. I would start over by attempting to resolve whatever made you think you could not use lists. If you need a more detailed treatment, please post a separate question; this comment box is much too small.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage a text based "screen", you would be better off using the curses module. This is designed exactly for what you want, though it is somewhat complicated. Also, you could make your program about eighteen times shorter by using more functions, because you are repeating the same code many times.